# Meteor mobile app doesn't connect to the database

Tags: cordova, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app

I have meteor project that works fine on both the browsers and mobile simulators (Android and IOS), but when I try to test the project on a real Android device using `meteor run android-device --settings settings.json` the application doesn't connect to the database.
When I try to create new user using `Accounts.createUser({});` the application keeps on loading forever.

The following get printed to the console when I click on the button responsible for executing `Accounts.createUser({})` function:

> I20200713-17:33:49.559(4)? 07-13 17:33:40.057  3339  3339 I chromium:
> [INFO:CONSOLE(1901)] "outside", source:
> http://localhost:12640/__cordova/app/app.js?hash=059a6a7f3fc127a6b51eb77218dffb7cf0d622f0
> (1901)

Why the application doesn't work as expected on a real Android device?

Comment: Are there any errors on the server?

Comment: @user3807691 no errors shown in the server

Comment: How did you deploy the app to the server? Can you add anonymized configuration files for deployment and mobile config?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I am not deploying it, I am just running the project locally from my machine using `meteor run android-device --settings settings.json`

Answer (score 2):

--mobile-server

meteor run android-device --mobile-server http://your.server.ip:3000 --port 3000 --settings settings.json